# How to view the contents of digikams face detection training database?

Tags: kde

Where is the digikam face detection training database located? How can I view it's contents?

Comment: I'm thinking on `.digikam` or `.config/digikam`.

Answer (score 1):

Digikam is part of the KDE suite of programs.

There is a comment in the KDE bug tracking system where a user uses `sqlite` to count entries in the database.

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.kde4/share/apps/libkface/database/recognition.db 'select count(*) from opencvlbphistograms;'
6915
```

You can read the [bug report comment here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=323888#c5).